# Is there an equivalent to transferTo for AsynchronousFileChannel?

Tags: java, nio, dma, nio2

I've been playing around with NIO2 in Java 7 and I kind of assumed that the `AsynchronousFileChannel` would have a `transferTo` method like its synchronous `FileChannel` sibling.

I'm looking to perform a zero-copy transfer between a local file and an open TCP socket. I've tried to simply create a `FileChannel` and call `transferTo` with my `AsynchronousSocketChannel` as the last arg but in seeing as the async socket version isn't a `WritableByteChannel`, Java won't have it.

With that ruled out as an option, does anybody know of a workaround or external library that would allow me to pipe bytes to an `AsynchronousSocketChannel` leveraging DMA (and by implication using no buffers in user-space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transferTo() isn't an asynchronous operation. So performing it on an asynchronous channel makes no sense. So it isn't provided.

Comment: The fact still remains that moving data from async file channel -> async socket channel involves creating an intermediate bytebuffer which could be avoided with `transferTo`, albeit on a different thread; transferTo's synchronicity doesn't come into it. [this discussion](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nio-dev/2011-December.txt) suggests that there's general interest but no specific timeline. Maybe I'll see if I can cook something up myself...

Comment: @ChrisMowforth It should also be noted that the alleged kernel-only implementation described as a possibilry in the Javadoc doesn't actually exist, at least in the Windows, Solars, and Linux implementations I have sourc code access to. It is implemented as you would do it yourself, with a direct byte buffer and a loop. That would demotivated providing it as well.